# DateTime format in XSLT

Tags: sql, xslt

Good morning! Can you format this 2001-12-31T12:00:00 in xslt?

Here's my current query in the xslt but the result is showing as 7/20/2018 08:45:27 AM

```
         <xsl:variable name="Date">
           <xsl:variable name="sqlXref">
                  SELECT GetDate() AS 'CURRENT_DTTM' FROM IMAGES_DETAIL (nolock) WHERE IMAGE_ID = '123456'
              </xsl:variable>
         <xsl:value-of select="env:ExecuteScalar($provider, $connStr, $sqlXref)"/>
         </xsl:variable>
```

Here's my xslt

```
           <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
      <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"

          <xsl:template match="Document">       
                    <xsl:element name="Document">
                      <xsl:element name ="TransactionId">
                    <xsl:value-of select="ImageId"/>
                   </xsl:element>               

             <xsl:element name="RequestDateTime">
              <xsl:value-of select="$Date"/>
          </xsl:element>                      
             </xsl:template>
           </xsl:stylesheet>
```

The business would rather want this kind of format:2001-12-31T12:00:00

Please advise if that is possible in xslt 1.0 version

Comment: It looks like you are using SQL server. In which case, you could just change your SQL query to return the date in the format you want rather than get XSLT to format it; `SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(19), GETDATE(), 126) AS 'CURRENT_DTTM'` (No need for the FROM clause either here, by the way).

Comment: @Tim C thanks for your help again :-) My xslt is working now..

Answer (score 1):

If the format will always be like that, you could do something like:

```
<xsl:value-of select="translate(substring-before(env:ExecuteScalar($provider, $connStr, $sqlXref), '.'), ' ', 'T')"/>`
```

Comment: Thanks @wasmachien. Sorry for the confusion if I do the  SELECT GetDate() AS 'CURRENT_DTTM' FROM IMAGES_DETAIL (nolock) WHERE IMAGE_ID = '123456' the result is 7/20/2018 10:45:27 AM.  How do I convert it to this format: 2001-12-31T12:00:00?

Comment: I tried adding <xsl:value-of select="translate(substring-before(env:ExecuteScalar($provider, $connStr", $sqlXref), '.'), ' ', 'T')"/>  the element <RequestDateTime></RequestDateTime> shows blank or empty after the xslt transform.

Comment: @Les in that case you have to replace the argument of the `substring-before` function with `$Date`, if that indeed contains the date string.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the final template to be able to get the date format: 2018-07-23T10:12:38

```
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
      <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
      xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" 
      xmlns:env ="urn:envision">

       <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
       <msxsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes"></msxsl:text>

       <xsl:variable name="ImageId" select="descendant::ImageId"/>
       <xsl:variable name="connStr" select="concat(env:GetScriptingLookup ('@CONN'), 'Trusted_Connection=YES')" />
       <xsl:variable name="provider">System.Data.SqlClient</xsl:variable>

       <xsl:variable name="Date">
            <xsl:variable name="sqlXref"> 
               SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(19),GETDATE(),126) AS 'CURRENT_DTTM' FROM IMAGES_DETAIL (nolock) WHERE IMAGE_ID = &apos;<xsl:value-of select="$ImageId"/>&apos;
            </xsl:variable>
            <xsl:value-of select="env:ExecuteScalar($provider, $connStr, $sqlXref)"/>
        </xsl:variable>

          <xsl:template match="Document">       
                   <xsl:element name ="TransactionId">
                      <xsl:value-of select="TranID"/>
                   </xsl:element>               

                    <xsl:element name="RequestDateTime">
                  <xsl:value-of select="$Date"/>
                </xsl:element>        

                   <xsl:element name ="ImageId">
                         <xsl:value-of select="ImageId"/>
                   </xsl:element>                             
               </xsl:template>
         </xsl:stylesheet>
```